# Set UITableview cell image from url in iOS

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios7

I am setting image on UITableViewCell using image url ,but the images doesn't get load unless i scrolls the UITableView.Here is the code that i have been using,i got to know about SDWeb Image library to download images from url,but i does;t want to use any library.Please tell me what aim doing wrong in this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    // Configure the cell...

    NSDictionary *dictCard=[cardsDetailsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:10];
    UILabel *dateLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:11];
    UIImageView *cellImage=(UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:0];


    CGSize firstSize=CGSizeZero;
    if([[dictCard objectForKey:@"orientation"]isEqualToString:@"1"]){
        [cellImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 75, 68)];
        firstSize=CGSizeMake(75,68);
    }
    if([[dictCard objectForKey:@"orientation"]isEqualToString:@"0"]){
        [cellImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 107, 72)];

        firstSize=CGSizeMake(107,72);
    }
    [cellImage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    NSString *string=[dictCard objectForKey:@"email_sent"];
    NSArray *items = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];



    dateLabel.text=[dictCard objectForKey:@"date"];
    nameLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sent to %d People",[items count]];


    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:(NSString *) [dictCard objectForKey:@"card_thumbnail"]];
    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response,
                                               NSData * data,
                                               NSError * error) {
                               if (!error){
                                   UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
//i am scaling the image here
                                        UIImage *imageScale=[self imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:firstSize];
                                        [cellImage setImage:imageScale];
                               }

                           }];




    return cell;
}
```

I have also added [__tableViewDraft reloadData];after setting the cell image but due to this my cell keeps on changing its cell image.

Answer (score 0):

Once the image has been downloaded, you need to ask iOS to refresh the cell. Check out `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`, among others.

Typically you might have have cells backed by CoreData objects and download and save the image to the managed object. You'd then have an `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` trigger an update when the managed object changes, refreshing the row.

Comment: can you please make some edit in code in order to have better understanding for me.Thanks